# getNetworkCountryIso() returns empty only on Galaxy s5

Tags: java, android

Using the Given code i am able to get country code for galaxy s4 but i am unable to get country code on galaxy 25

```
public String GetCountryZipCode() {
    String CountryID = "";
    String CountryZipCode = "";

    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) LoginActivity.this
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    // getNetworkCountryIso
    CountryID = manager.getNetworkCountryIso().toUpperCase();
    String[] rl = this.getResources().getStringArray(
        R.array.CountryCodesNew);
    for (int i = 0; i < rl.length; i++) {
        String[] g = rl[i].split(",");
        if (g[1].trim().equals(CountryID.trim())) {
            CountryZipCode = g[0];
            break;
        }
    }

    return CountryZipCode;
}
```

Comment: your device is dual sim?

Comment: No dual sim. plus i have no sims in the phones.

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkCountryIso(). User should be registered to network to get this info. So having sim installed and connected is required (unless CDMA phone)

Comment: Only when your device has a SIM in and is registrered to a GSM network the NetworkCountryISO ist set. Because it is set by the broadcast cell of the network, saying where it is located. Used to detect roaming!

Comment: I have used the s4 with sim only once. Currently the s4 does not have any sim still it shows country code, but when i do the same thing with s5, it only shows country code when the sim is inserted and not when the sim is not inserted.